# Automate Export Server Package daily

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, backup

I have a IIS 7 server which hosts 19 applications internally. 
As part of daily backup process is there any way to automate the **Export Server Package** feature that can run on a daily basis at a specified time and dump the package zip file on a network drive.
Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by telling the **windows task scheduler** to run the **msdeploy** command line recurrently.

1. Create a batch file with the following content:

   ```
   set currentDate=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%

   "c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" ^
     -verb:sync ^
     -source:webServer ^
     -dest:archivedir=c:\iisBackup\%currentDate%
   ```

   Running this batch should backup your complete IIS instance into `c:\iisBackup`.
2. Schedule the batch. Run:

   ```
   schtasks -create -sc DAILY -tn BackupIis -tr PathToYourBatchFile.bat
   ```